# incorrect argument to 'decltype'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> convert(int argument)
{
}

int main()
{
  decltype(&convert<int>);
  return 0;
}
```

The following gives this error for Visual Studio 2010:

```
error C3555: incorrect argument to 'decltype'
```

Why?

I'm tring to create a std::map where the key is an enum and the value is a function.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `std::function` over function pointer?

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/23dd38ae5a2a1e6c3fcf0428dbf7f649 works correct.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. Note that the `decltype` line doesn't have any effect.

Comment: That missing declarator part is typo? since you can't skip that in that case

Comment: `decltype(&convert<int>);` doesn't declare anything, substite with something like this `decltype(&convert<int>) foo;`. And only the signature of `convert` function is needed then you could remove the empty body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[VS2010 bug](http://softnfuzzy.blogspot.be/2011/12/decltype-on-visual-studio.html). That link also has a workaround:

```
template <typename T> T identity(T);
decltype(identity(&convert<int>));
```

Comment: The line: std::map<Type, decltype(identity(&convert<int>))> convert_functions; is giving the dialog: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler has stopped working :(

Comment: @Baz: You might need a typedef to capture the result. But that's stacking workaround on workarounds.